# Clickable Image Areas with varying image size

Tags: html, css, image

For a slideshow site, I have to display images of varying sizes which may be 300*250 to 1200*1800. I am aware of image maps, but they come with fixed dimensions requirements i.e. one needs to define specific area through coordinates like coords="0,0,82,126").
I have two questions:
1) Is there a way to make it variable, like 10% of left side image area should link to previous image, and 10% of right side image area should link to next image. For example, if an image is 300*300 px size, then 30px (horizontal bar area) from the left and 30 px from the right should be the clickable area
2) Is there a CSS way to display left and right arrows on the above mentioned areas, like we usually see while navigating Facebook albums. The only difference is that these left and right arrows should actually show up in TRANSPARENT form on top of the left and right clickable areas on the images, overlapping with image for the width of the arrow picture.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started.

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1%;
  display: table;
}
#images {
  position: relative;
}
#left, #right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#left {
  left:0;
}
#right {
  right:0;
}
.arrow {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
background: transparent;
border-top: .4rem solid white;
border-right: .4rem solid white;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 lightgray;
transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.arrow.left {
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) rotate(-135deg);
}
.arrow.right {
  right: 40%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow:hover {
  border-top: .4rem solid white;
  border-right: .4rem solid white;
  box-shadow: .2rem -.2rem 0 white;
}
.arrow:hover.left {
  left: 10px;
}
.arrow:hover.right {
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
</body>
</html>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="images">
      <img src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/39758696/6/stock-photo-39758696-man-on-top-of-skyscraper.jpg">
    
      <div id="left"><a href="#" class="arrow left"></a></div>
      <div id="right"><a href="#" class="arrow right"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Done! Thanks Again